# Catel setting DataContext for nested view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, catel

Please help me with a problem. Why is the constructor with the signature does not work. And how to determine DataContext for ServerTabView? As I understand, now DataContext for ServerTabView inherited from a parent - MainWindowView, because ServerTabView is nested in it. Then how to get the right to receive ServerTabView DataContext?

`MainWindowView`:

```
<catel:DataWindow x:Class="ServerUI.Views.MainWindowView"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
              xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ServerUI.Views"
              Width="640"
              Height="480"
              ResizeMode="CanResize"
              ShowInTaskbar="True"
              SizeToContent="Manual"
              WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
              WindowState="Normal">

<!--  Resources  -->
<catel:DataWindow.Resources />

<catel:TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
    <TabItem Header="__Server__">
        <views:ServerTabView DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="__Clients_">
        <views:ClientsTabView DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </TabItem>
</catel:TabControl>

</catel:DataWindow>
```

`ServerTabView`:

```
<catel:UserControl x:Class="ServerUI.Views.ServerTabView"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com">

<catel:StackGrid>
    <catel:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </catel:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>

    <catel:StackGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </catel:StackGrid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="IP Address" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ServerIpAddress}" />

    <Label Content="Port" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ServerPort}" />

    <Label Content="Directory" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Catalogue}" />

    <catel:EmptyRow />

    <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Command="{Binding StartServer}"
            Content="Start" />

    <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Command="{Binding StopServer}"
            Content="Stop" />
</catel:StackGrid>

</catel:UserControl>
```

`ServerTabViewModel`:

```
    public class ServerTabViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IServerServices _serverServices;

        public ServerTabViewModel(Server server, IServerServices serverServices)
        {
            Argument.IsNotNull(() => serverServices);
            Argument.IsNotNull(() => server);

            _serverServices = serverServices;
            Server = server;

            StartServer = new TaskCommand(OnStartServerExecuteAsync);
            StopServer = new TaskCommand(OnStopServerExecuteAsync);
        }

        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the property value.
        /// </summary>
        [Model]
        public Server Server
        {
            get { return GetValue<Server>(ServerProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ServerProperty, value); }
        }
        // ModelToViewModel Properties
        //...
   }
```

And some debug inormation:

```
11:57:00:464 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Providers.LogicBase] [10] DataContext of TargetView 'ServerTabView' has changed to 'MainWindowViewModel'
11:57:00:466 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Providers.LogicBase] [10] Using IViewModelFactory 'Catel.MVVM.ViewModelFactory' to instantiate the view model
11:57:00:466 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [10] Creating instance of type 'ServerUI.ViewModels.ServerTabViewModel' using specific parameters. No constructor found in the cache, so searching for the right one
11:57:00:467 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [10] Checking if constructor 'public ctor(Server server, IServerServices serverServices)' can be used
11:57:00:468 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [10] Constructor is not valid because value 'ServerUI.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel (ID = 1)' cannot be used for parameter 'ServerUI.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel (ID = 1)'
11:57:00:468 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [10] The constructor is valid and can be used
11:57:00:469 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [10] No constructor could be used, cannot construct type 'ServerUI.ViewModels.ServerTabViewModel' with the specified parameters
11:57:00:469 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [10] Creating instance of type 'ServerUI.ViewModels.ServerTabViewModel' using specific parameters. No constructor found in the cache, so searching for the right one
11:57:00:469 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [10] Checking if constructor 'public ctor(Server server, IServerServices serverServices)' can be used
11:57:00:470 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [10] Constructor is not valid because parameter 'server' cannot be resolved from the dependency resolver
11:57:00:470 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [10] The constructor is valid and can be used
11:57:00:470 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [10] No constructor could be used, cannot construct type 'ServerUI.ViewModels.ServerTabViewModel' with the specified parameters
11:57:00:471 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelFactory] [10] Could not construct view model 'ServerUI.ViewModels.ServerTabViewModel' using injection of data context 'MainWindowViewModel'
11:57:00:471 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Providers.LogicBase] [10] Used IViewModelFactory to instantiate view model, the factory did NOT return a valid view model
System.Windows.Data Error: 3 : Cannot find element that provides DataContext. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'ClientsTabView' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

How result - `ServerTabViewModel(Server server, IServerServices serverServices)` dont fireup.

**Update**_____________________________________________________________________

`MainWindowViewModel`

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
    }

    public override string Title => "WatcherServerUI";
}
```

How should i instantiate `Server` here? I mean, what is good approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the logging, the current DataContext for the nested views (in this case `ServerTabView` and `ClientsTabView`) is `MainWindowViewModel`.

Constructing view models in Catel can happen in 3 ways:

1. With explicit model injection (then you need to set the DataContext)
2. Automatic resolving from the IoC container
3. A combination of 1 and 2

Since you specified a `Server` parameter with additional injected services in your view model, you choose for option 3. This means that you will need to set the `DataContext` to a valid `Server` object. You haven't posted the code for `MainWindowViewModel`, but let's assume there is a public property named `Server` on that vm.

```
<TabItem Header="__Server__">
    <views:ServerTabView DataContext="{Binding Server}" />
</TabItem>
```

As you can see instead of passing `{Binding}` (which results in `MainWindowViewModel`), you should use `{Binding Server}` which results in a server instance and will be used to instantiate the nested view model.

Comment: POST UPDATE. No, I haven't this property in my `MainWindowViewModel`.There is nothing i have. How should i do this?